# react virtualized in react-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I am trying to use react virtualized in my react-rails code.
I have the minified version of the library and added the require statement in application.js
Yet, when I try to create a List, it shows List not defined error.

```
application.js
//= require react-virtualized.min.js

code that creates list
<List
   width={100}
   height={100}
   rowCount={list.length}
   rowHeight={20}
   rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
/>
```

Comment: Please show us your code in the description, rather than describing it, otherwise we can't see any mistakes.

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve].